# Android Exoplayer live audio stream vu meter audio visualisation and recording

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am using Exoplayer to stream live audio. I can't use MediaPlayer as my audio is 16 and 32 KBPS which caused a huge 60 second delay when using MediaPlayer but it streams right away when using Exoplayer as I can adjust the buffer size for exoplayer.

I would like to have a vu meter audio visualization in my app. Does anyone know how I can achieve it? How can I get the audio levels from exoplayer?

Also is there a way to record the audio stream so that I can save it to disk?

Here's how I am streaming:

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxx.mp3");
ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);

Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "SPLENDID");
DefaultUriDataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(getContext(), new TransferListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransferStart() {
        //System.out.println("onTransferStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBytesTransferred(int bytesTransferred) {
        //System.out.println("onBytesTransferred: "+bytesTransferred);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransferEnd() {
        //System.out.println("onTransferEnd");
    }
}, userAgent);
ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(streamurl, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT);

CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        System.out.println("onPlayerStateChanged, playWhenReady: "+playWhenReady+" ,playbackState: ");



    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {
        System.out.println("onPlayWhenReadyCommitted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
        System.out.println("onPlayerError: "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```

**CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:**

```
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSource;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

/**
 * Created by pranoychowdhury on 11/14/16.
 */
public class CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer extends MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer {
    public CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(SampleSource source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public CustomMediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(SampleSource source, Handler eventHandler, EventListener eventListener) {
        super(source, eventHandler, eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean processOutputBuffer(long positionUs, long elapsedRealtimeUs, MediaCodec codec, ByteBuffer buffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo, int bufferIndex, boolean shouldSkip) throws ExoPlaybackException {
        //return super.processOutputBuffer(positionUs, elapsedRealtimeUs, codec, buffer, bufferInfo, bufferIndex, shouldSkip);

        boolean processed = false;

        //  Clone buffer

        ByteBuffer clone = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffer.capacity());
        buffer.rewind();//copy from the beginning
        clone.put(buffer);
        buffer.rewind();
        clone.flip();



        processed = super.processOutputBuffer(positionUs,elapsedRealtimeUs,codec,buffer,bufferInfo, bufferIndex, shouldSkip);
        if (processed & !shouldSkip)
        {
            // send data to be converted to shorts and then propogate a callback to render float data
            //transform(clone);
            //System.out.println("Buffer: "+clone.toString());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

EDIT: I downgraded the `Exoplayer` to 1.5.3 as I couldn't figure out how to access the `MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer` in the v2.

I extended the `MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer` class as it has a processBuffer function I can override.

However now I am stuck at how to convert the `ByteBuffer` to calculate the audio power levels for the visualization.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this.

Comment: @YLS sorry, I didn't find any usable solution